# when customer login my related and upsells not display

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my related and upsells.

When a customer login, my related and upsells not display in product_view.

Comment: Are you responsible for any custom code or themes in your install? How much do you know about your code base?

Comment: And, where do these blocks display when there is no active customer login? Are they in the left or right column? Does the overall template change when the customer is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three most likely ways in which this can happen involve the following:

1. Layout XML
2. PHP/PHTML
3. CSS

**Layout XML:** `grep` your layout xml for `<customer_logged_in>` and see if there are any `<remove />` nodes referring to these blocks. Also check for `<action>` tags with `unsetChild` method calls that refer to these blocks.

**PHP/PHTML:** It's possible that the templates and class definitions for these blocks have had logic added to them to check for customer logged in state. This would be an inefficient way to accomplish this, but it's possible. You'll need to check the templates (google for *Magento template path hints*) and the block classes in which they are rendered; see if they have been customized.

**CSS:** This is the most unlikely candidate, but I've seen developers set `display:none` based on `<body>` classes added via layout XML. This could be seen as an `addBodyClass` call in the `<customer_logged_in>` layout update handle, which I described how to find above.